# Seeking visuals of two 2-spheres intersecting transversally in 4-space

Tags: geometry, visualization

Are there available on-line graphics of a pair of 2 spheres  intersecting transversally in 4-space?  I guess the two natural ways would both be *Flatland*-style depicting successive 3-d sections: either as an animated video or more simply by drawing successive sections in 3-space.  Successive 3-d sections of a 2-sphere appear first as a point in 3-space and then as expanding circles, then shrinking back to a point.

But if there is a better way to visualize it, that is good for me too.

I would like to be able to refer students to such a thing without having to figure it out in TikZ, for LaTeX.  I'm not good at 3-d in TikZ.